# Does "bash: command: command not found" return false?

Tags: bash, perl

I am writing a script to automate the configuration of software. I want to begin by checking to see if the script needs to install the software first, then configure it. If I was to check `$ software --version` and I get `bash: command: command not found`, then I know that I will want to install it first.

Does `bash: command: command not found` return false?

Edit: For any answers, could the answer be explained?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

```
$ spamegg
spamegg: command not found

$ echo $?
127
```

You could just do:

```
if software --version &>/dev/null; then
   ## True, do something
else
   ## False, do something
fi
```

Comment: Odd, this answer was in the review queue as "flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." Looks long enough to me! (+1)

Comment: Hey @heemayl could you explain your answer for me?

Comment: @NAltun The basic answer is if a command is not found it, bash will call a function in some systems or simply shows that the command is not found..in both cases the exit status will be greater than 0 i.e. truth value will be false..

Comment: @Sparhawk, you might be interested in the [Meta post](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3833/135943) on that subject.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard I agree that high-rep users often post low-rep (and too-short) answer. However, this particular answer seems that it should be long enough to skip that review queue.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, I don't think your approach is the best way to tackle this problem. The reason being is just because a command returns *not found*, doesn't mean the program isn't *installed*. It could simply indicate that the program is not located in any of your PATH locations.

Perhaps, a better way would be to this is actually check against the list of installed packages:

**RHEL/CentOS:**

```
grep PROGRAM_NAME <(rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}\n")
```

**Debian/Ubuntu:**

```
grep PROGRAM_NAME <(dpkg --get-selections | awk '{ print $1}')
```

Comment: While I like the solution, I don't agree with your argument. If `command` is installed but not found in PATH, it's unlikely to be usable anyway.

Comment: I see your point, however, a `program` could be installed in `/sbin` (restricted to root by default) and this user could simply have limited `sudo` access. If the user mistakenly  does a blind install with a `-y` flag assuming that application is not installed, it could lead to an unintentional upgrade.

Comment: But doesn't handle self compiled programs, whilst the path method does...

Comment: @PaulCalabro In that case the installation script should simply run with root privileges (why whould a simple user need to install software only root can run?). In fact, the installation script is likely to run with root privileges anyway.

Comment: @Martijn: That's a fair argument for other approach.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: You're assuming this is an end-user. This could be a _service account_ used  for configuration management. You might want said account to have the ability to _install software_ (with privs granted via sudo), but not necessarily want it to be able to run `/sbin/fdisk` on your system. And you should avoid running as root when possible. `sudo` is more auditable.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to check whether a particular command is available, you should do so instead of trying to execute it:

```
if command -v spamegg >/dev/null; then
  echo spamegg is available
else
  apt-get install spamegg
fi
```

Trying to execute `spamegg` to see if it's available is a bad approach. First, it obfuscates your code, making it look like `spamegg` is used to install something. Second (and more importantly), the command your're checking might exist but simply fail for some reason:

```
if grep >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo grep is available
else
  echo grep is not available
fi
```

This will output `grep is not available` even when it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
# example you need wget and your PATH is okay then:
# bash/ksh/.. will return exit code 127 if command not found
# 
# redirect stdin and stderr to the /dev/null = if exist, 
# output is not interesting
wget --help >/dev/null 2>&1
stat=$?   # variable ? include last command exit status
echo "exit status:$stat"
if ((stat == 127 )) ; then # not exist/found
   echo "install wget"
   exit 1
fi
echo "wget exist, continue"
```

You can use also if before command, but that handle all exit codes which are not 0.

You can do any command and test exit code using if

```
# if command ; then 
#     works fine
# else
#     not so fine
# fi
```

```
# negative testing ! = if not exit code 0 then
if ! wget --help >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
   # give err msg to the stderr and exit 
   echo "install wget / wget didn't work correctly" >&2
   exit 1
fi
echo "wget works fine"
```

Before test it with if, look first working exit code

```
wget --help
echo $?
# will echo 0 = ok. not 0 is not ok
# if command return not 0, then  you can't test using if, you need
# test using exit value = 127
```